# Determining where a group will direct an addition

Tags: aromatic-compounds

I'm looking at a phenol with a ketone in one of the meta positions being treated with $$ \frac{Cl_2}{AlCl_3} $$

I know the Alcohol is the stronger activator because ketone is a deactivator. I'm wondering how determine the major product of the addition.

I'm thinking the Cl will add to the other meta location of the Alcohol group due to it wanting more space around the ring, but I'm not sure if that's correct, due to not being sure how to determine where something will direct and addition.

Comment: No point in adding AlCl3 to phenols.